# What's the equivalent of Angular's $q in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-promise

What's the equivalent of Angular's $q in Angular2? 
Specifically, I'm looking for `$q.when`, which allowed you to do something like:

```
return $q.when(['TestResponse']);
```

Comment: EcmaScript 6 [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Does the native promise have a when equivalent?

Comment: `Promise.resolve(['TestResponse'])` should do the trick

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  if(xxx) {
    resolve('ok');
  } else {
    reject('error');
  }
}).then(x => doSomething())
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
or http://learnangular2.com/es6/promises

Comment: What if we're stuck at using ES5? What should we do?

Comment: IMHO stay with Angular1.x

Comment: That's of course an option. But in slow migration scenarios a solution can help.

Comment: Actually I don't know about ES5 with Angular2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the native ES6 Promise. One of the main reasons to make the new angular is ES6 and the upcoming ES7.